# Line integral equals zero because the vector field and the curve are perpendicular.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $F: \Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ defined as $F(x,y) = (-y,x)$ and $\gamma:[0,2] \to \mathbb R^2$ defined as $\gamma(t) = (R(1-t), 0)$ for some $R>0$. We have
$$ 
\int_{\gamma}\vec F \cdot \vec {d\ell}= \int_{0}^{2}\langle \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
R(1-t)
\end{bmatrix} 
,
\begin{bmatrix}
-R \\
0
\end{bmatrix} 
\rangle
dt = 0
$$

Supposedly this is because in this case $F$ and $\gamma$ are perpindicular but I'm having trouble seeing why.
If I try to visualize the image of $F$ I think it sort of looks like a spiral rotating anti-clockwise (?), and the image of $\gamma$ simply as the segment $[-R, R]$. How are they perpindicular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vector field $\mathbf{F}(x,y)=(-y,x)$ does indeed point in a circular (not spiraling) way, centered at the origin. So on the $x$-axis, it's pointing up to the right of the origin, and pointing down to the left of the origin. Those up and down directions are perpendicular to the horizontal direction that the segment $\gamma$ travels in.

You can see this algebraically in the calculation you did: For $y=0$ (as we have when $(x,y)=\left(R(1-t),0\right)$), $\mathbf{F}(x,y)=(0,x)$ points vertically, perpendicular to the horizontal $\left(R(1-t),0\right)$. You can see this graphically in the following image, produced with the Mathematica code `Show[VectorPlot[{-y,x},{x,-1,1}, {y,-1,1}],ParametricPlot[{2(1-t),0},{t,0,2}]]`:

[image: arrows filling the plane pointing in circles, and a horizontal line in the middle]